# redirection SplashScreen to MainScreen when logged in

Tags: android, authentication, activity-lifecycle

I have 3 activities: SplashScreen, LoginScreen, MainScreen

Splash -> Login -> Main -> go to Home System (if BackButtonPressed)

I'd like to redirect Splash on Main when app is launched again and user is logged:

Home System -> App -> Splash -> Main (if logged)

I am newbie in these cases, please give me any tip.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    Thread time = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginScreen.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    time.start();
}

}
```

Login

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {
// variables

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    Button mSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

}



public void attemptLogin() {

   /*
            Validate code
      */
    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // perform the user login attempt.
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}


}
```

Main

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(a);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    Button mLogOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_out_button);
    mLogOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginScreen.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Can you add some pseudo-code to represent what you are trying to do and what's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set SplashScreen (only Splash) with this Intent Filters in Manifest:

```
 <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

When Splash launch Login, you must have (on Splash):

```
finish();
```

When Login is successfully and goes to Main, you mast have the same (on Login):

```
finish();
```

When you load LoginActivity (onCreate) you must check if user is logged. In this case, launch Main and do (on Login):

```
 finish();
```

Comment: That make sense. Now I try to implement sharedpreferences for check login status.
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(IsLogged()==true){
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);`

App crashed

Comment: That is another question